# MySQL customized join query using multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am searching one student from each class from one group. There are different class groups and every group has different classes and every class has multiple students. See below:

```
Group1 --> Class1, Class2 etc
Class1 --> GreenStudent1, GreenStudent2 etc
Class2 --> RedStudent1, RedStudent2 etc
------------------------------------------------------

SELECT 
   table1.id,
   table1.myname,
   table1.marks
   table2.studentid,
   table2.studentname
FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.oldid = table3.id
   INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.studentid = table3.newid
WHERE 
   table1.classgroup = 'SCI79' 
GROUP BY table1.oldid
ORDER BY table1.marks DESC
```

There are different joins applied in the query. Above mentioned query giving me correct results but I need little modification in it. Current query returning me one student from each class.

What I need? I need one student from each class but only that student who has MAXIMUM

```
 table1.marks
```

So I should have one student from each class who has maximum number in their relevant classes. Can anyone suggest some solution or rewrite this query? Thanks :)

Comment: It would help to show some actual structure of the table (at least per join and columns) and sample data to show normalized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery on an `INNER JOIN` should handle this:

```
SELECT t1.id
   ,t1.myname
   ,maxMarks.marks
   ,t2.studentid
   ,t2.studentname
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.oldid = t3.id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.studentid = t3.newid
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id
      ,MAX(marks) AS marks
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id
) maxMarks ON t1.id = maxMarks.id
   AND t1.marks = maxMarks.marks
WHERE t1.classgroup = 'SCI79'
GROUP BY t1.oldid
ORDER BY t1.marks DESC
```

Joining the aggregated table with MAX back on itself should filter down the result set to each student and their individual highest marks.

**EDIT**

I think I misread your original question ... you wanted students only that have the `MAX(marks)` period? in that case, use this query:

```
SELECT t1.id
   ,t1.myname
   ,t1.marks
   ,t2.studentid
   ,t2.studentname
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.oldid = t3.id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.studentid = t3.newid
WHERE t1.classgroup = 'SCI79'
   AND t1.marks = (
      SELECT MAX(marks) AS marks
      FROM table1
   )
GROUP BY t1.oldid
ORDER BY t1.marks DESC
```

This `WHERE` clause will only return students that have marks matching the MAX mark in the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the max function, something like:

```
where table1.marks = max(table1.marks)
```